# JavaFX Drag and Drop Image into GridPane (FXML, Controller Class)

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, drag-and-drop, fxml

I am working currently on a game which works similar to the one asked already here: [JavaFX Drag and drop to GridPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088095/javafx-drag-and-drop-to-gridpane) .

I have a Splitpane and on the left side a Gridpane and un the right side some Images(Imageview).
I Want to drag an image to a field in the Gridpane.

I am new to JavaFX and especially Gridpane and Drag and drop. That's why I worked with much code of the already asked questions.

I tried to adapt the code form those examples into my Controller Class but it won't work.

edit:

Are the Fields in the Grid an object, which would mean I could say something like event.getTarget = Image? or do I have to set objects/nodes in the fields which can be handled?

edit:

Controller Class:

```
 import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;

public class FXMLSTPreFieldController {
    @FXML
    private ImageView bomb;
    public GridPane Board;


    final GridPane target = Board;

    // Event Listener on ImageView[#bomb].onDragDetected
    @FXML
    public void Drag(MouseEvent event) {
        Dragboard db = bomb.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putImage(bomb.getImage());
        db.setContent(content);

        event.consume();
    }

    @FXML
    public void Over(DragEvent event) {
         if(event.getGestureSource() != target && event.getDragboard().hasImage()){
             // moving
             event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
         }
         event.consume();
    }


    @FXML
    public void Drop(DragEvent event) {
        //Data drop
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        boolean success = false;
        Node node = event.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
        if(node != target && db.hasImage()){

            Integer cIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(node);
            Integer rIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(node);
            int x = cIndex == null ? 0 : cIndex;
            int y = rIndex == null ? 0 : rIndex;
            target.add(bomb, x, y);

            ImageView bomb = new ImageView(db.getImage());

            Board.add(bomb, x, y, 1, 1);
            success = true;
        }
        event.setDropCompleted(success);

        event.consume();
    }

    @FXML
    public void Exit(DragEvent event) {
//        //mouse moved away, remove graphical cues
//        bomb.setVisible(true);
//        target.setOpacity(1);
//
//        event.consume();
    }

    @FXML
    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
        //The drag-and-drop gesture entered the target
        //show the user that it is an actual gesture target
        if(event.getGestureSource() != target && event.getDragboard().hasImage()){
            bomb.setVisible(false);
            target.setOpacity(0.7);
            System.out.println("Drag entered");
        }
        event.consume();
    }

    @FXML
     public void Done(DragEvent event) {
        //the drag and drop gesture has ended
        //if the data was successfully moved, clear it
        if(event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE){
            bomb.setVisible(false);
        }
        event.consume();
    }

}
```

Comment: The `LoadException` is saying that your `FXML` file has no `Controller`. And it doesn't. If it had a `Controller` it would have something similar in the `FXML` file. `<ImageView fx:id="bomb" fitHeight="81.0" fitWidth="89.0" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="422.0" onDragDetected="#bombDrag" onDragDropped="#bombDrop" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" fx:controller="package.YourController">`

Comment: @Sedrick Okay thanks didn't saw that. Another question: Are the Field in the Grid an object, which would mean I could say something like event.getTarget = Image? or do I have to set objects/nodes in the fields which can be handled? How can I Drag and drop them into the Gridpane? Why isn't my Code working?

Comment: Since you are not really familiar with Javafx, I suggestions you not try to make and Image be one FXML file. Create everything that is static using one FXML. Then create the dynamic nodes in the code.